# Heat flow derivative of entropy

Tags: pr.probability, parabolic-pde, linear-pde

In a 1966 paper (Speed of Approach to Equilibrium for Kac's Caricature of a Maxwellian Gas, Arch. Rational Mech. Anal., Vol. 21), McKean seems to suggest that the successive derivatives of entropy $H (f) = - \int f \log f $ of a probability density $f$ along the heat flow have alternating signs. Is there anything proved today in this respect?

Comment: Thank you. Are these references about f a probability density on R^n, f_t the convolution with a Gaussian kernel, and the derivatives are taken along H(f_t)?

Answer (score 2):

McKean's conjecture was proven already in 1967 by Stewart Harris, see [Proof that Successive Derivatives of Boltzmann's H Function for a Discrete Velocity Gas Alternate in Sign](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1705172?journalCode=jmp).

See also [On the sign of successive time derivatives of Boltzmann's H function](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/3/4/002) (1970); [Do the higher derivatives of the H-function alternate in sign?](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00420175) (1983); [Alternating signs of the higher derivatives of the H- function for a nonlinear model Boltzmann equation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0378437185900342) (1985).

Answer (score 1):

For scalar random variables, the signs of the first four derivatives have been shown to be alternating. This is in ["Higher order derivatives in Costa’s entropy power inequality"](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&user=bTVgLkQAAAAJ&citation_for_view=bTVgLkQAAAAJ:eQOLeE2rZwMC) by Fan Cheng and Yanlin Geng. The question for higher derivatives seem open to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Do you know the name of the paper?

Comment: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7274074